# Filter to return two Max numbers

Tags: c#, performance, linq

Is there a way I can combine the below two queries to return two numbers with a single query.

```
var maxIDOne = mydb.GetMyData()
                   .Where(x => x.MyTypeID == 1)
                   .Max(x => x.ID);
var maxIDTwo = mydb.GetMyData()
                   .Where(x => x.MyTypeID == 2)
                   .Max(x => x.ID);
```

Comment: You're looking for `GroupBy(x => x.MyTypeID)`.

Comment: MyTypeID can be also be values other than 1 and 2.

Comment: Yeah so `Where(x => new [] { 1, 2 }.Contains(x.MyTypeID)).GroupBy(x => x.MyTypeID)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var mydb = new[]{
    new MyType{ MyTypeID = 1, ID = 2},
    new MyType{ MyTypeID = 1, ID = 3},
    new MyType{ MyTypeID = 2, ID = 5},
    new MyType{ MyTypeID = 2, ID = 4},
};

var vals = from mt in mydb
           where mt.MyTypeID == 1 || mt.MyTypeID == 2
           group mt by mt.MyTypeID into g
           select new { MyTypeId = g.Key, MaxID = g.Max(x => x.ID)};
```

Returns

[image]

Comment: Except, you're not using the fluent syntax. How about showing that, too?

Comment: They are the same thing. I feel in this case it reads cleaner this way but it is a 1x1 mapping between them.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the result you want, something like this may work:

```
var maxIdOneAndTwo = mydb.GetMyData()
   .Where(x => x.MyTypeID == 1 || x.MyTypeID == 2)
   .GroupBy(d => d.MyTypeID)
   .Select(g => new {
      MyTypeID = g.Key,
      MaxID = g.Max(x.ID)
   });
```

For the record I didn't refer to any outside resource in order to compose this answer.